# Abstracts and implementation architecture of a Typescript code

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I know this might be wrong but I will still need your help. Thanks!

Please, what can you say about abstracts and implementation architecture of the code?

I need ideas. Thanks.

```
export interface IDataService<T> {
    getAll(): Promise<DocumentType<T>[]>;
}

export interface IServiceRequestService extends IDataService<IServiceRequest> {

}

export class ServiveRequestService implements IServiceRequestService {
    private readonly ServiveRequestModel: DistanceModelType

    constructor() {
        this.ServiveRequestModel = getModelForClass(ServiveRequest);
    }

    public getAll(): Promise<DocumentType<IServiceRequest>[] {
        return this.ServiveRequestModel.find();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, what's the question?  Please consider following the guidelines for [ask].  Right now I have no idea what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello @jcalz. I just need an abstract explanation of the code.

Comment: I don't know what "an abstract explanation" is, and without any context or a [mcve] it's hard to begin to understand what the code is about.   I can't tell if there's a language barrier here (are you fluent in English?) but I still don't know what is happening here so I don't think I can help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  But the fact that the class relies on some external function `getModelForClass` seems like not a great design.

Comment: You probably want this service to be an instance of a more generalized service instead of a class.  I can write an answer with what I think the code should look like.  But I don't know what the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiveRequestService` is a `class` meaning that you can create many instances of it by calling `new`.  What is the difference between those instances?  There isn't any, which indicates that the `ServiveRequestService` should be an instance of some other class instead of a class of its own.

We can make a generic class `DataService<T>` that takes the specific model as an argument in its constructor ("dependency injection").  This removes the need to rely on the external `getModelForClass` function.  In general, a class should encapsulate is own logic so it's not a great design to rely on an outside method.

```
export interface IDataService<T> {
  getAll(): Promise<DocumentType<T>[]>;
}

export class DataService<T> implements IDataService<T> {
  private readonly model: Model<T>;

  constructor(model: Model<T>) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  public getAll(): Promise<DocumentType<T>[]> {
    return this.model.find();
  }
}
```

```
const ServiveRequestService = new DataService(ServiveRequestModel);

const all = ServiveRequestService.getAll();
```

If the `ServiveRequestModel` has the right type (`Model<IServiceRequest>`), then the generic `T` will get inferred automatically and `all` will have type `Promise<DocumentType<IServiceRequest>[]>`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gYwK4FsIDtgBVwQDxYB8UAvFAN4CwAUAL400QAeYcATsFAJaYRsBmAQwTQAsnAAmEADYFiValCj8eEgBQBKAFxQACmzgouAZ3zxkaTDkhyA2gF1CNetUYt2nHsD5CRUAJIwgsCCAMp8AG5cInIUNEoA5hDAAILS0po6%20oYmZoioGNi4do4A3M4M1MysHFAI0oLGxrDBYZHR%20ETcKGDSEJbAzYGt4WxRMV0KSmBsXBHB0GwQghJw6NIgUCiSMjriUrJE5a6KdWvGwGxICMDsatsHezuHhBpxp0rAABYmAHQPMlIW2exyULniUDASAARtJolAkql0pk9AYjKY8OYClZikQHPIIUolsAkGx0FBvn8AdJfip0OoNKCoC5wdRQJAAqNxhAAEoQACOSAgFyB5FZUnqgiWZ3QIq5c15AqFF32uygqtk-nlIj5guFwCcJwQ5048oiir1F210DI6AgAHcWiFrWozRblcANYzKsbZZxBOksmjcpj8gNrPgte0dUr9YR8UC3bqPdbfoi0hlGUA)